# Comparing string elements stored in ArrayList

Tags: java

I have a string arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and I have stored string values inside. Now i want to do something like

```
data.get(0) == "a" // (need to compare)
```

How can I do? please help out.

Answer (score 6):

use `list.contains(Object o)` to check if list contains `String`. For comparing of `String` use `"a".equals(list.get(0))` method.

Comment: Small point, I recommend "a".equals(list.get(0)) instead of list.get(0).equals("a")

Comment: @smas You're right, it prevets potencial NullPointerException if null is in array list. I've edited it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some code to play with:

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
data.add("a")
data.add("b")
data.add("c")
```

To check for [equality](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
data.get(0).equals("a"); // true
data.get(0).equals("b"); // false
```

To check for [order](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29):

```
data.get(0).compareTo("a"); // 0 (equal)
data.get(0).compareTo("b"); // -1 (a is less than b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data.size() > 1 && "a".equals((String)data.get(0))) {
  //do something
}
```

You should really use generics:

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
if(data.size() > 1 && "a".equals(data.get(0))) {
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is basic operations on Array and String. You have answer for your questions in Michal's post. But you can read some guide about it and do it by yourself

Oracle have nice tutorial about [Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and for String you can find "String comparison" or just find method to compare in [documentation String class in Java 1.6](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)